# If I <think> I'm going to be late, I'll call you

Tags: if, think

> If I **think** I'm going to be late, I'll call you. ([source](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/if-i-will-be-late-i-will-call-you.770643/))

**Question:** Is **think** a dynamic verb (rather than a stative verb)?

I think that **think** is semantically in the future, but I am not sure.

Comment: "To think (that something is true)" is a stative verb. Stative verbs describe states of being or existence, rather than actions or processes. They typically refer to things like feelings, emotions, beliefs, and states of knowledge.

Comment: There's a lot of rubbish spouted in the thread you linked to!

Comment: Thank you, FumbleFingers. Is "think" semantically in the future?

Comment: I'd say *always*, after ***if***, since that implies whatever the subject thinks is currently unknown. Why? *Because he hasn't thought it yet!*

Comment: ...actually, there's a "timeless" usage in, say, *We disagree on everything! If I think X is true, he will say it's false!* But I don't see what use it is to ask whether "think" is past, present, or future. You could say *If I thought I was going to be late, I'd call you* with exactly the same meaning as your cited text, so don't let anyone tell you "thought" is *only* the past tense of "think".